# SHA1 hashed password converted to object if is replaced in JSON object

Tags: json, sha1, hashcode

I would like to ask on this:

I have object with data for request and i would like to hash value options.data.password:

**Here is how i do it:**

```
var hashedPassword = CryptoJS.SHA1(options.data.password);
alert(hashedPassword); // This is correctly value 
options.data.password = hashedPassword;
```

Problem is that if i looked into updated JSON object i saw something like this:

[image]

But i was expected just hashed string value, not object.

**NOTE:** If I update value manually (without hashing function) is everything displayed correctly.

How can i solve it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [CryptoJS documentation](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Output):

> The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a hex string.

Your property assignment and subsequent `JSON.stringify` do not know you want to use it as a string.

You need explicitly make it a string by calling its `.toString()`. Again, from the docs:

> You can convert a WordArray object to other formats by explicitly calling the toString method and passing an encoder.

```
options.data.password = hashedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

FYI, The receiving end of this hash needs to know what encoding method was used (Base64 in this example) in order to accurately work with it.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of CryptoJS:

The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a hex string.

The JavaScript object returned has a toString() method which is why when you use it as a string (in alert) it gets converted to one.